# why does the jpa object has suffix like "$$_jvstdd3_6"?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I used spring data jpa. and my code like `city = cityRepository.findOne(cityCode);`, i expect the city is the Domain object, but i found the object like [image: object] with some magic suffix($$_jvstae5_6)
,i used the spring data jpa, that's my questions. can you help me?

Comment: the relationship is `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "large_area_code") private LargeArea largeArea`

Comment: JPA (I suspect hibernate) always creates a proxy of your object, this is needed to be able to track changes in your objects.

Answer (score 0):

Does your entity contain a lazy relationship?

If so that´s probably a proxy around your entity to provide such functionality like lazy loading.

Comment: Hi, No, there is not Lazy relationshop, the relationshop is only this, `    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "large_area_code")
    private LargeArea largeArea;`, the default should be EAGER